# Automatically trigger script function when the "send" button is pressed on the gmail app

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

How do I tie/trigger a Google app script function to the Gmail Compose send button?
something like this:

```
SendButton.addClickHandler(CalendarFunction);
var CalendarFunction = app.createServerClickHandler("CalendarFunction")

function calendarfunction {
etc****
```

I want to create a script that will allow users to add calendar info from inside the gmail compose box.

```
 "3 hours, Meeting, 4/03, 4:00pm".
```

Just trying to save time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking is possible. However you can do this:

1. Send an email to a special address (yourname+calendar@gmail.com) and have the date, time, body of reminder in the subject
2. Use an app script working via time based trigger to search your gmail inbox periodically to pick up the said email
3. Use the subject of the email to set the calendar entry
4. Delete the email
5. Set an Archive rule so that mails sent to yourname+calendar@gmail.com do not hit the inbox

Comment: I'll try to make this, even though it probably won't be much of use in real life. Thanks.